# Find duration longer than 16 seconds with Regex

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex and I've come across a problem that I can't quite figure out.

I'm getting pushed some data regarding to phone calls and I would like to filter out all calls that are 16 seconds or less.

Example of what is pushed through:

- Duration=0:00:12
- Duration=0:12:47
- Duration=0:00:17

The time can be anywhere from 1 second to 99 hours. Any help on this or even where to start would be great.

edit: Sorry I should have added I need to use regex as this is being pushed into Google Analytics as an event and I'm setting up a Goal to show it as a conversion only if longer than 16 seconds. The duration is pushed through in the Event Label.

Comment: You don't need regex. Split the string, parse the time string as actual time and check the result

Comment: `^Duration=0:00:(0?[0-9]|1[0-6])$` will pick up the <=16s ones - try online https://regex101.com/r/8TEek8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches all lines with a duration of 16 seconds or less:

```
Duration=0:00:(0|1[0-6])
```

This one matches all lines with a duration greater than 16 seconds:

```
Duration=([1-9]|0[1-9]|0:[1-5]|0:0[1-9]|0:00:[2-5]|0:00:1[7-9])
```

Take your pick - wasn't clear which way you wanted the filter to run.